# window event (hide, destroy) in the same class as creating it

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygtk

Hello there !
I recently tried to use less Glade and use more Python for the app and i am wondering if i can hide the window in the same class as creating it in a certain event (example: when i click a button).
I tried searching the same question but sadly i did not find anything. The keywords i tried:

> *hide a window in the same class as creating it*

I don't connecting the window object but i need to know this because it would make everything easier.
This is the code when i noticed i can't used it like that (check line 39):

> https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ewuheyiqor.py

So basically i want to show the window and "hide" it until i want to show it again.
Thank You in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the window by clicked a button

```
button.connect ('clicked', window.hide)
```

but how do you propose to show it again with a button which inside the "hiding" windows ? (the button also hidden)